# JSTL Статический код в jsp

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

Здравствуйте есть коды в jsp который позволяет добавить ответ на вопросу и увидеть все ответы.В БД ответ хранит id вопроса.
чтобы видеть ответы есть такой метод:

```
    <c:forEach items="${findAllAnswersByQuestionId}" var="name">
    ${name.text}
    <input type="hidden" value="${name.id}" name="questionId">
</c:forEach>
```

backend-овский часть не важно что там происходит.Ответ можно дать через id вопроса.так когда запускается программа в браузере появится вопрос когда нажимаем на эту вопросу работает этот часть `${findAllAnswersByQuestionId}` и запомнит id вопроса потом есть форма которая добавляет ответ:

```
   <spring:form action="/addAnswer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="addAnswer">

    <spring:textarea path="text"></spring:textarea>
    <input type="file" name="pict">
    <input type="submit" value="add">

</spring:form>
```

в верху на 3 строке есть такой код `<input type="hidden" value="${name.id}" name="questionId">` здесь он запомнит id вопроса и когда мы нажимаем на add ответ в бд сохраняется под соответствующим вопроса так как если мы добавили ответ на вопросу у которому есть 4 id ответ сохраняет собой и id вопроса в бд. проблема в том что если добавим этот код `<input type="hidden" value="${name.id}" name="questionId">` в цикле и мы ответим на вопросу у которому 4 id он в бд сохраняет под 16 id это происходит так потому что он каждый раз идет от всех вопросов Если мы не пишем код внутри этого цикла тогда вот этот часть не работает `value="${name.id}"`  потому что этот name мы даем от сюда, `<c:forEach items="${findAllAnswersByQuestionId}" var="name">` можно ли так сделать чтобы этот часть `<c:forEach items="${findAllAnswersByQuestionId}" var="name">` каким образом стало типо статическим чтобы было доступно по всему классу?